# UWP ComboBox SelectedItem does not bind as expected in flyout

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I fail to use the `SelectedItem` property of the `Combobox`. An item is correctly bound and displayed, but can not be changed to another one. If one tries to select an other item, the item list is correctly closed, but `SelectedItem` is not called (nor setter or getter) and the shown selected item is not changed.

My XAML is as follows:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding PasswordTypes}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PasswordTypeTemplate}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPasswordType, Mode=TwoWay}"
    />
```

relevant `ViewModel` code:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    //these are the only two assignments in code of those two properties
    _passwordTypes = new ObservableCollection<PasswordType>(nonEmptyList);
    _selectedPasswordType = PasswordTypes.First();
}

private PasswordType _selectedPasswordType;
public PasswordType SelectedPasswordType
{
    get => _selectedPasswordType;
    set => Set(ref _selectedPasswordType, value);
}

private ObservableCollection<PasswordType> _passwordTypes;
public ObservableCollection<PasswordType> PasswordTypes
{
    get => _passwordTypes;
    set => Set(ref _passwordTypes, value);
}
```

Calls to the two the properties are as follows:

1. `get PasswordTypes` originating from `this.InitializeComponent()`
2. `get SelectedPasswordType` originating from `this.InitializeComponent()`
3. `set SelectedPasswordType` originating from `this.InitializeComponent()` to `null`
4. `set SelectedPasswordType` originating from `this.InitializeComponent()` to an instance of `PasswordType` (`_passwordTypes.Contains(value);` evaluates to `true`)
5. no further calls are made to the two properties afterwards

And here's what I'm seeing:
[image: ComboBox behaviour]

I've created a branch with the minimal changes I needed to write this question: https://github.com/famoser/Bookmarked/compare/bug-failing-combobox

If I replace `ComboBox` with `ListView`, the `SelectedItem` is set correctly. The setup is therefore working correctly.

Do I need to set additional properties for the `ComboBox` for this to work, or is this a bug?

Comment: Why are you using this in your binding: Source={StaticResource Locator} ?

Comment: I've simplified the code and forgot to remove this (My `ViewModel`s are properties in the `Locator`). Thanks!

Comment: My suspicions fall on the item template... does this work if you remove 'ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PasswordTypeTemplate}"'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason that it's not working is because your `ComboBox` never gets focus so the `SelectionChanged` event never gets fired.

This behavior is by design from Windows 10 build *14393* onward. The fix is simple - you just need to manually enable **focus on interaction** on your `AppBarButton`.

There's a new property called `AllowFocusOnInteraction` introduced in *14393* that does just this. So if you target *14393* and later, setting it to `false` is all you need to do.

If you target anything before that, you will need to do the following in the `Loaded` event of your `AppBarButton` .

```
private void AppBarButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var allowFocusOnInteractionAvailable =
        Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsPropertyPresent(
            "Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement",
            "AllowFocusOnInteraction");

    if (allowFocusOnInteractionAvailable)
    {
        if (sender is FrameworkElement s)
        {
            s.AllowFocusOnInteraction = true;
        }
    }
}
```

To read more on this behavior, please refer to Rob Caplan's excellent post ["ComboBox on a Flyout attached to an AppBarButton loses mouse input on 1607"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2016/09/14/combobox-from-an-appbarbutton-loses-mouse-input-on-1607/).